# Пытаюсь написать код который выдаст мне погоду в моем городе на pyowm

Tags: python

Есть простецкий код, написан то по инструкции с гитхаба, но кода решил проверить что он мне выведет получил ошибок на всю командную строку

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('myToken')

observation = owm.weather_at_place('Kiev')
w = observation.get_weather()

print(w)
```

https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm
Тут всё по инструкции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и ошибочка

Буду благодарен если скажите где я затупил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю ошибка в том, что не нашел твой город https://openweathermap.org и сайт читает кириллицу то наст русский язык

Вот рабочий код:

```
import pyowm

owm =  pyowm.OWM('myTokenyour_token',language = "RU")

place = input("В каком городе/стране?: ")
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + 
w.get_detailed_status())
temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
print('Температура в районе: ' + str(temp) + '°C')
```