# Добавление информации о погоде в приложение

Tags: python

Разрабатываю приложение для дома, хочу узнать, как добавить туды информацию о погоде на сегодня с какого-либо сайта (хотя бы температуру) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть решение для Python - [pyowm](https://pypi.org/project/pyowm/) 
На GitHub страница с документацией. Думаю, затруднений не вызовет - документация подробная

Если что, на русском город нужно писать, но указав language - [Пытаюсь написать код который выдаст мне погоду в моем городе на pyowm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963129/%D0%9F%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pyowm)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ